Finding the ratio at which diagonals divide each other, in quadrilateral $ABCD$ with vertices $A(1,5)$, $B(4,1)$, $C(7,5)$, and $D(4,9)$

Find the ratio in which the diagonals of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ divide each other if the vertices are $A(1,5)$, $B(4,1)$, $C(7,5)$, and $D(4,9)$.

I realize that if I find the equations for the lines $AC$ and $BD$, I can find the intersection point, but the book I am referring to hasn't introduced finding equations of lines yet, so is there any alternate method?
I am trying to get a general method for all such types of questions.

Hint: Draw the figure.

@Blue I tried but didn't get any idea.

AC is a horizontal line.  BD is a vertical line.

Per your edit, you want a general method. Since you're going beyond the specific scenario of the book's question, it's not unreasonable that you'll require techniques beyond what the book has covered thus far. So: Go ahead and solve your self-imposed problem by finding the equations of lines. If you like, you can revisit the problem attempting another technique, with the answer you found via equations serving as a target.

@Blue Thanks for the idea, motivation and inspirition

BTW: (Focusing on convex quadrilaterals) A diagonal divides the quadrilateral itself into two triangles. The ratio at which it divides the length of the other diagonal is equal to the ratio of the areas of those triangles. (Why?) So, if you known the formula for the area of a triangle using the coordinates of its vertices, then you're done! :)

Hint:
$ABCD$ is a quadrilateral whose co-ordinates of the end points are given.
Now if you carefully observe then you will see that $ABCD$ is a rhombus.
Let me explain why ?
Length$(AB)=\sqrt{(1-4)^{2}+(5-1)^{2}}=5$
Similarly
Length$(CD)=\sqrt{(7-4)^{2}+(5-9)^{2}}=5$
Therefore
Length$(AB)=$ Length$(CD)$
Similarly
Length$(AD)=$ Length$(BC)$
You can prove by the above formula.
Therefore we can say that $ABCD$ is a rhombus.
Now let the diagonal intersect each other in the ratio $k:1$
Now the co-ordinates of the mid-point of the diagonal is $P(\frac{7+1}{2},\frac{5+5}{2})=P(4,5)$
Or, you can also say that the mid-point of the diagonal is $P(\frac{4+4}{2},\frac{9+1}{2})=P(4,5)$
Now you have to use the formula  :
$(4,5)=\left(\frac{kx_{2}+x_{1}}{k+1},\frac{ky_{2}+y_{1}}{k+1}\right)$
Now let's take into consideration $x_{1}=1, x_{2}=7, y_{1}=5, y_{2}=5$
Which implies $$\frac{7k+1}{k+1}=4$$ and $$\frac{5k+1}{k+1}=5$$
Now $\frac{5k+5}{k+1}=5$ is meaningless.
Therefore solving $\frac{7k+1}{k+1}=4$ gives $k=1$.
Therefore the required ratio is $1:1$

This is not a rectangle. It's a parallelogram.

$ABCD$ is not a rectangle, but it happens to be a rhombus. Knowing that, the analysis is a bit overkill if we "know" that the diagonals of a parallelogram (of which both rectangles and rhombi are instances) bisect each other. ... In any case, OP mentions wanting a "general method", not merely a solution to specific problem.

Ok. Sorry for the mistake. But is my answer correct ?

Kindly inform me
